# как обновить модификаторы opencart 3 через ftp

Tags: opencart

Не очистить кеш модификаторов а именно бновить! Очистить не помогает, стоит тема Journal2 и нужно именно обновление!

Answer (score 1):

После инсталляции в админке вы должны были увидеть попап, в котором предлагалось вынести папку **`storage`** за педелы корневой папки сайта. Какой путь вы тогда выбрали, там и кеши модификаторов, собсно в папке **`storage/modification`**. Если вы просто закрываете этот попап не внося никаких изменений, папка storage будет в **`system/storage/modification`**. Достаточно её полностью очистить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: суть в том что доступа к админке нет! Через админку и так ясно. Обычно ваш вариант работает, но не для темы Журнал2 там в обязательном порядке нужно обновить а не очистить кеш